# disabling few rows in spark datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-spark

Is there a way in spark datagrid to disable some rows programmatically, in flex 3, it could be done using the function mouseEventToItemRenderer this way:

```
override protected function mouseEventToItemRenderer (
            event: MouseEvent): IListItemRenderer {
    var listItem: IListItemRenderer;// = super.mouseEventToItemRenderer(event);
    if (_disableFlag) 
    {
        if (listItem) 
        {
            if (listItem.data) 
            {
                if (disabledRow(listItem.data)) 
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return listItem;
}
```

And then I implement the function disabledRow to return true or false depending on some condition, the condition that will specify if the selected item will be renderered or not. Is there a way in spark datagrid to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's how I did

**First Step**

I created the classes SelectionIndicator, HoverIndicator and CaretIndicator like the ones we find as skin parts in the datagrid skin, so the skin part caretIndicator:

```
<!--- @private -->        
<fx:Component id="caretIndicator">
    <s:Rect implements="spark.components.gridClasses.IGridVisualElement">
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import spark.components.DataGrid;
                import spark.components.Grid;

                /**
                 * @private
                 */
                public function prepareGridVisualElement(grid:Grid, rowIndex:int, columnIndex:int):void
                {
                    const dataGrid:DataGrid = grid.dataGrid;
                    if (!dataGrid)
                        return;

                    const color:uint = dataGrid.getStyle("caretColor");
                    caretIndicatorFill.color = color;
                }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>

        <s:stroke>
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="caretIndicatorFill" color="0x0167FF" weight="1"/>
        </s:stroke>
   </s:Rect>
</fx:Component>
```

becomes

```
package com.tn.zuro.components
{
    import mx.graphics.SolidColorStroke;

    import spark.components.DataGrid;
    import spark.components.Grid;
    import spark.components.gridClasses.IGridVisualElement;
    import spark.primitives.Rect;

    public class CaretIndicator extends Rect implements IGridVisualElement
    {
        private var caretIndicatorFill:SolidColorStroke ;

        public function CaretIndicator()
        {
            super();
            caretIndicatorFill = new SolidColorStroke();
            this.stroke = caretIndicatorFill;
        }

        public function prepareGridVisualElement(grid:Grid, rowIndex:int, columnIndex:int):void
        {
            const dataGrid:DataGrid = grid.dataGrid;
            if (!dataGrid)
                return;

            const color:uint = dataGrid.getStyle("caretColor");
            caretIndicatorFill.color = color;
        }
    }    
}
```

The same goes for SelectionIndicator and HoverIndicator, just don't forget to use SolidColor instead of solidColorStroke and the property fill or Rect instead of the property stroke.

**Second Step**

In the personalized datagrid, I added event listeners for the events gridClick, gridRollOver and gridMouseDown:

```
this.addEventListener(GridEvent.GRID_CLICK, gridClickHandler);
this.addEventListener(GridEvent.GRID_ROLL_OVER, gridEventHandler);
this.addEventListener(GridEvent.GRID_MOUSE_DOWN, mouse_down_handler);
```

And here are the event listeners:

```
protected function mouse_down_handler(event:GridEvent):void
{
    if (_disableFlag)
    {
        if (event.item)
        {
            if (disabledRow(event.item))
            {
                event.grid.caretIndicator = null;
                event.grid.selectionIndicator = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected function gridClickHandler(event:GridEvent):void
{
    if (_disableFlag)
    {
        if (event.item)
        {
            if (!disabledRow(event.item))
            {
                event.grid.selectionIndicator = new ClassFactory(SelectionIndicator);
                event.grid.caretIndicator = new ClassFactory(CaretIndicator);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected function gridEventHandler(event:GridEvent):void
{
    if (_disableFlag)
    {
        if (event.item)
        {
            if(disabledRow(event.item))
            {   
                event.grid.hoverIndicator = null;
            }
            else
            {
                event.grid.hoverIndicator = new ClassFactory(HoverIndicator);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You probably already guessed that _disableFlag and disabledRow are respectively a Boolean and a Function. Now the last step is the easiest:

**Third Step**

When you use the personalized dataGrid, if you want to disable the columns, you set _disableFlag to true and implement the disabledRow which returns true if a condition is met, and false if not

```
<custom:NinjaGrid id="ninja"
                 _disableFlag=true
                  creationComplete="ninja_trainingCompleteHandler(event)"/>
```

---

```
protected function ninja_trainingCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    ninja.disabledRow = beNinja;
}
private function beNinja(ninja:Object):Boolean
{
    if (ninja.knowHowToWalkOnWater == true)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This solution doesn't work for the selection mode multiple rows, I found another solution for the multiple rows selection mode.

---

### Second Solution

In this solution, I use only the HoverIndicator component, the event listener for the rollover event will remain the same. I don't use the event listener for the click event anymore, and in the mouse_down_handler function, I have now this code:

```
protected function mouse_down_handler(event:GridEvent):void
{
    if(_disableFlag)
    {
        if (event.item)
        {
            if (!disabledRow(event.item))
            {
                if (!event.ctrlKey)
                {
                    tempItem = event.item;
                    tempSelecteditems = new Vector.<Object>();
                    tempSelecteditems.push(tempItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempSelecteditems.indexOf(event.item) < 0)
                    {
                        tempSelecteditems.push(event.item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempSelecteditems[tempSelecteditems.indexOf(event.item)] = null;
                    }
                }

            } 
            else
            {
                if (!event.ctrlKey)
                {
                    selectedItem = tempItem;
                    tempSelecteditems = new Vector.<Object>();
                } 
                else
                {
                    if (tempSelecteditems.length)
                    {
                        selectedItems = tempSelecteditems;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        selectedItem = tempItem;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the spark datagrid supports the gridrollover event. under that we can get the

itemrender i think this might be suitable for you

for further reference please refer the [Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html)